# Dual Boot Ubuntu 18.04 & Windows 10, cannot connect to ethernet in Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, ethernet, nic

I recently installed Ubuntu on a machine that runs windows 10.  Everything works except for Ubuntu connecting to the wired internet (no wifi).  The internet works in windows.  I have tried a few things, including editing the /etc/network/interfaces file to include enp3s0.  Since this didn't work I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: You should provide us more information, like your result of "ip addr" or "ifconfig" commands. You can provide list of your services as well. (service --status-all)

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of these terminal commands: `ip addr show` and also: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.